# Can't import tkinter, tkinter is not defined - it seems not to be the usual problem

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Python3 gives me this or other errors, whatever method i use to import tkinter.

I searched online a solution to my problem but none worked. I am running the latest version of Ubuntu.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
def main():
    main_window = tkinter.Tk()
    main_window.title("free communism here")
    click_function = print("WEWE")
    communism_button = tkinter.button(text = "click for free communism", command = click_function, height = 40, width = 120)
    communism_button.pack()
    tkinter.mainloop()
main()
```

The result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "communism button.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()
  File "communism button.py", line 4, in main
    main_window = tkinter.Tk()
NameError: name 'tkinter' is not defined.
```

I can't figure out why the program doesn't work. It should display a button and if you press it, it should display "WEWE". Sorry for my probably bad english.

Comment: You imported all names from namespace tkinter, not the namespace itself. Remove the tkinter. The maniloop() should be main_window.mainloop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the fact that you use `from tkinter import *` and then use the button function as `tkinter.Button`. When you use `from xxx import *` you don't use the 'xxx' package name anymore (so just `Button()`). Otherwise just use `import tkinter`, after which you do use `tkinter.Button()`.

I personally prefer `import xxx` for larger scripts, because it's more clear where a method comes from.

Besides that, your code still has another problem with your 'click_function'. You should make that an actual function. And tkinter.Button() is with a capital 'B'

```
import tkinter
def click_function():
    print("WEWE")

def main():
    main_window = tkinter.Tk()
    main_window.title("free communism here")
    communism_button = tkinter.Button(text = "click for free communism", command = click_function, height = 40, width = 120)
    communism_button.pack()
    main_window.mainloop() # call here main_window instead of tkinter
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
def main():
    main_window = Tk()
    main_window.title("free communism here")
    click_function = print("WEWE")
    communism_button = Button(text = "click for free communism", command = click_function, height = 40, width = 120)
    communism_button.pack()
    main_window.mainloop()
main()
```

Comment: My example shows you what you did wrong while importing tkinter  that doesn't mean that your code will work because of your click_function defininition!

Comment: Thanks, now the program starts. But... Why if i click the button it doesn't print "WEWE", but prints it at the start of the program?

Comment: @xevius48_dev: That's because you just defined click_function as a variable that runs while executing `main()`. Make it an actual separate function. See the edit in my answer.